# How to configure my AWS Lambda to access internet without NAT in a public subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 3 public subnets, one in each availability zone.

These subnets connect via route table to one internet gateway.

My ec2 instances in these public subnets can connect fine to the internet.

I created one AWS Lambda instance and did notice that all api calls to the internet fail with timeout.

The `lambda is also located in the same public subnets` so I don't understand why this is the case ?

I would totally understand that a lambda in a private vpc requires a NAT Gateway to connect to the internet but in my scenario I am lost.

My lambda security groups looks like:

- inbout - no rules
- outbound - `IPv4  All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Egress Rule`

Lambda VPC configuration:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you deployed the lambda in your VPC? Can you show us the lambda networking configuration?

Comment: Hi Paolo. Yes I am sure and will share a screenshoot while hiding sensitive data. I checked in Lamba -> Configuration -> VPC and clearly see there that the lambda is inside the vpc and the public subnets

Comment: Does the lambda have a network interface associated to it?

Comment: @Paolo no. The lambda has only vpc and subnets attached to it.  Lambda is deployed via serverless like the file I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77159110/how-to-debug-bref-laravel-serverless-lambda-timeout

Comment: I noticed that the lambda can resolve hosts. I created one api endpoint (lambda is laravel in php) and does return the result of `return dns_get_record('google.com');` but it cannot make curl/http calls to public internet resources. If I add a call to a public api like this one it fails with timeout `$client->get(sprintf('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/%s', random_int(1, 10)));`

Comment: Upon creation the lambda function should end up with a network interface attached to it (which is the actual networking component). Can you check whether it exists and whether it has a public ip associated to it?

Comment: @Paolo updated the question with the screenshoot of lambda vpc config. How can I find the network interface in which UI menu ? The lambda is used via aws api gateway which is created by the serverless file

Comment: You won't see it from there. Look for network interface in the console and check for any of the subnets.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I see 3 network interfaces for my lambda, one for each region. THe public ipv4 ipv6 fields are `-` so seems like it does not have public ip https://ibb.co/Px4n5qB

Comment: Well that's the issue. Most likely the subnet does not have auto-assign IP enabled. The network interface must have a public ip for internet access

Comment: I see thanks. Any though how can I solve this while still using serverless ? I am using serverless and terragrunt/form for provisioning the infrastructure and deploying the lambdas.

Comment: I'm not familiar with serverless.. but you know need to make sure the network interface has a public ip.

Comment: I created my vpc and subnets with terragrunt https://ibb.co/PFVzCym. I will see to make changes to ensure the network interface of lambda receives public ip

Comment: Please share all information in the question. Show us how you're creating the subnets/lambda function in the question

Comment: Lambda functions can be behind NAT or they can be outside the VPC entirely.  They cannot have public IPs so they cannot talk to the internet through an IGW.  Correct, this is *un*like EC2 instances.

Comment: Thank you both. Thanks @erik258 I will check in detail the other post which will take some time and reply later. Meanwhile will also try and assign manually a public ip to the network interface and try again my lambda

Comment: To reiterate, you *cannot* connect a public IP to a lambda.  It can only work through NAT or if the function isnt' in a VPC in the first place.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-networking.html

Comment: @erik258 are you sure about that? check the second answer in the link you shared

Comment: Nonetheless, this is a duplicate

Comment: No  frankly I appear to be out of date as of 2019.

Comment: @Paolo I did associate one elastic IP via AWS UI to the network interface in zone a and initially it did not work. Then I assigned 1 elastic ip also to the network interface in zone b and c and my lambda could connect to the internet. I did this for learning purpose and you statement was totally right: a lambda within a public subnet and with network interface with a  public ip can and did access the internet. The only thing is that we have no clue in what a-z is deployed and have to assign public(elastic) ip to each of them. I will look into how to automate this

Comment: @KristiJorgji glad you got things working

Comment: @Paolo in case you know, do I get charged for the elastic ips attached to the lambda network interfaces ? As per the explanation here https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges I believe I will get charged as they are not ec2s.. but I attach eip to 3 network interfaces

Comment: @KristiJorgji I would guess so, but best for you to check with AWS support